# Why my document update in meteor method with $addToSet do nothing?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to develop a system where users can create topics and join topics created by other users. In my exemple, they are two user ("A" and "B"), the user "A" create a topic, and the user "B" join this topic.

When "A" create a topic (logged with "A"), I initialize like this :

```
topic.users = [{userId: this.userId, admin: 1}];
Topics.insert(topic);
```

Then, when i check mongo with Topics.find(), i have something which seems good:

```
{ "_id" : "8FDCyKssnrGxqvAep", "users" : [ { "userId" :"vQIMLMo5CK9YqxpTZ", "admin" : 1 } ] }
```

When "B" (logged with "B") join the topic i call:

```
Topics.update(topicId ,{ $addToSet: { users: { userId: this.userId, admin: 0 }} });
```

the update return "undefined", and i except, after the update, to have in my document something like:

```
{ "_id" : "8FDCyKssnrGxqvAep", , "users" : [ { "userId" :"vQIMLMo5CK9YqxpTZ", "admin" : 1 }, { "userId" :"AlsA4q
5PS5s5ts", "admin" : 0 } ] }
```

I have also try to do:

```
Topics.update({_id:topicId, 'users.userId': {$ne: this.userId}}, {$push: {users: { userId: this.userId, admin: 0 }}});
```

But when i check Mongo, i still have:

```
{ "_id" : "8FDCyKssnrGxqvAep", , "users" : [ { "userId":"vQIMLMo5CK9YqxpTZ", "admin" : 1 } ] }
```

The update do nothing and they are no error message

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT 12/12/2015:

When I try to do update in client side, it's work good.

```
function joinTopic(topicId)
{
var user = Meteor.user();
Topics.update(topicId ,{ $addToSet: { users: { userId : user._id, admin: 0 }} }); 
}
```

But i have a problem when i want to use call function. In client side I have:

```
function joinTopic(topicId)
{
 Meteor.call('joinTopic', { topicId: topicId });
}
```

and in server side, i have:

```
joinTopic: function (topicId)
{
Topics.update(topicId ,{ $addToSet: { users: { userId : this.userId, admin: 0 }}});
}
```

Comment: have you enable update from client?

Comment: Tried your solution with $addToSet. That works. After updating, the users array has a new element with user B and admin=0. And when repeated, nothing is changed. This is all by design, so stick to your $addToSet solution because it will prevent duplicates in the users array. BTW, what is that second comma in the mongo output between the topic id and users array?

Comment: @perusopersonale i use update in server side

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart I have edit my post

Comment: @JosHarink SOrry, the coma is a copy/paste error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found my stupid mistake ! 
I had to do:
Meteor.call('joinTopic', topicId);

instead of:
Meteor.call('joinTopic', { topicId: topicId });